# Error of writeJPEG in R: image must be a matrix or array of raw or real numbers

Tags: r, arrays, jpeg

I created a 4-layer `RGBA` array and would like to convert it into a JPEG image. I get this error and I cannot understand what it means:

```
image must be a matrix or array of raw or real numbers
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem.
Here is my code:

```
red <- matrix(1:1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
green <- matrix(2:2, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
blue <- matrix(3:3, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
alpha <- matrix(0:0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

array1 <- abind:::abind(red, green, blue, alpha, along=0)

install.packages("jpeg")
library(jpeg)
image <- writeJPEG(array1, raw(), quality = 1, color.space = "RGBA")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `str(array1)` output?

Comment: According to the manual the array should have numbers ranging from 0 to 1. Your values typically do not do that. Also `dim( array1 )` will show you that you do not have 4 layers, but 5. Try with `along=3` for starters.

Comment: @mhovd  int [1:4, 1:5, 1:5] 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL

Comment: @Sirius Thank you for your suggestions.